# What is a good way to update a instance of a ArrayList object using threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, arraylist, reference

I am working on a project and for one part of my project I have as ArrayList of Strings I keep on record to hold onto incoming messages from other systems that are interconnected. This is a peer to peer design so I wanna have a BufferedReader ready to read any messages sent from any sockets to the system, so I designed a thread that, when created, creates a new thread for each socket that will listen to a specific input stream.

Right now I have attempted this using the following two private classes:

InputListener(inner class ListenerThread)

```
private class InputListener implements Runnable{
        private ArrayList<String> queue;
        private ArrayList<Stream> sockets;
        private ArrayList<Thread> threads;
        public InputListener(ArrayList<String> q, ArrayList<Stream> s)
        {
            this.queue = q;
            this.sockets = s;
            this.threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
            for(int i = 0; i < this.sockets.size(); i++)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(new ListeningThread(this.sockets.get(i).is, this.queue));
                t.start();
                threads.add(t);
            }
        }
        private class ListeningThread implements Runnable{
            private BufferedReader read;
            private ArrayList<String> queue;
            private boolean status;
            public ListeningThread(InputStream is, ArrayList<String> q)
            {
                this.read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                this.queue = q;
                status = true;
            }
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true)
                {
                    String str = "";
                    try {
                        str += read.readLine();
                        while(!str.equals("END"))
                            str += read.readLine();
                        this.queue.add(str);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    status = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(status)
            ;
    }
}
```

Stream

```
private class Stream{
    public InputStream is;
    public OutputStream os;
    public Stream(final Socket s)
    {
        try {
            this.is = s.getInputStream();
            this.os = s.getOutputStream();              
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return;
        }
    }

    public InputStreamReader getReader()
    {
        return new InputStreamReader(this.is);
    }

}
```

When I create the InputListener I pass a reference to a queue from another class, I am excluding this class to prevent over complicating this problem, so assume that this ArrayList is initialized and it's pointer(I cant remember what java calls it) is passed. My problem is that when I use a loop like the following, I just get trapped in an infinite loop

```
while(queue.size equals 0)
   Do nothing

Remove and do something with String at index 0 in queue
```

Can anyone help me with this problem? any help will be greatly appriciated!

Comment: were you able to solve this based on the answer provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use one of the specialized container classes in java.util.concurrent instead of a standard unsynchronized ArrayList.

For example, [LinkedBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html).

```
// in the setup
BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

// in producer thread
queue.put(work);

// in consumer thread
work = queue.take(); // blocking - waits as long as needed
```

I also suggest reading the Java Tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html). It is not a trivial subject.